# How to name a base class which holds Id and Name?

Tags: java, architecture, naming-conventions

I'm looking a name for a class in the system which has Id (Long) and Name (String) in a java environment.

Are their any conventions for this kind of class, or is it just architecture related?

Comment: The name of a class should be based on what it represents, and not on the types of any member variables (what if you added a new member or changed the type of an existing one?).

Comment: Or BaseClassThatHoldsNameAndId. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen some places where names such as `IdAndName` have been used. I don't like it. Such names are too coupled with the current status of the class. It is quite likely that new feeds will be added to/removed from this class and then the name will stop being accurate.

So, I would encourage you to think along both of these directions:

- What is this class representing? If this is the superclass of all "things" that have an "ID" and a "Name" then you can call it `NamedEntity` (the term `Entity` is quite common for describing persistent objects that maintain a distinct identity).
- (Alternatively) do you really want to make it a superclass that many other classes extend? Sounds as if you can move to a design were your entities will hold such an object in a field (as opposed to inheriting from its class). You can then introduce a `Nameable` interface which will define a `getId()` and `getName()` and have these entities implement these methods (cost in term of volume of code is marginal). This will give you better separation of concerns, less coupling (inheritance is the strongest form of coupling) and will not exploit the `extends` card which you can play only once.

Comment: Nameable interface sounds like a good idea. Keeping the coupling away.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it is application related. Sometimes (if all value objects need ID and Name) people call such class `BaseEntity` or `AbstractEntity`. If you want to use "cool" java convention call this class `Nameable`

Comment: Nameable would be better for interface

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard of a convention for such cases. Just ask yourself what is the class purpose and the magic noun will come up.

Answer (score 0):

What about **IdNamePair**? This would be similar to how other libraries name "pairs". For example:  KeyValuePair here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-7.0

But, assuming that all entities by definition must have an Id and a Name, you can just call it **Entity**. Here are other alternatives mentioned here:

1. BaseEntity
2. NamedEntity
3. AbstractEntity
4. IdNamePair
5. Nameable